# Excel VBA Currency Converter with Date and Amount as Input

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, currency

I'm trying to convert currency in Excel using website data. Inputs should be (Date, Amount, Currency). For example: A2="date", B2="amount", C2="currency in 3 letters"

I found this piece of code that uses this uses this website (https://www.xe.com/en/travel-expenses-calculator/) to input data and receive the exchange, but it's not working anymore. Any ideas?

```
Public Function Currency_Converter(date As String, Amount As String, Currency As String) As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As String
    Dim sBody As String
    Dim Method As String
    Dim Cash As Double
    Dim HC As String
    Dim Day As String
    Dim Month As String
    Dim Year As String
    
    M = "CC" 'Method
    HC = "USD" 'HomeCurrency
    URL = "https://www.xe.com/en/travel-expenses-calculator/getweathereport.php"
    Day = Left(date, 2) 'RecepitDay
    Month = Mid(date, 4, 2) 'ReceiptMonth
    Year = Right(date, 4) 'ReceiptYear
    
    sBody = "Method=" & M & _
            "&HomeCurrency=" & HC & _
            "&Receipt=" & Amount & _
            "&ReceiptCurrency=" & Currency & _
            "&ReceiptDay=" & Day & _
            "&ReceiptMonth=" & Month & _
            "&ReceiptYear=" & Year

    XMLPage.Open "Post", URL, False
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlenconded"
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
    XMLPage.send sBody
    
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
    value = Split(XMLPage.responseText, ";")
    Currency_Converter = Replace(value(1), ".", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a different website -- alphavantage --

They have api's for many functions, including currency.

In the UDF below, the date needs to be entered as a serial number.  So, for example `TODAY()`, or `DATEVALUE("9/15/2020")` would be valid arguments.  But `"9/15/2020"` would not.  But you can change that in the code if you want.

If you don't have one, there's a VBA JSON converter available on git-hub that I use in this UDF>

```
Function historicalForex(Optional Amt As Currency = 1, Optional sFrom As String = "EUR", Optional sTo As String = "USD", Optional dt) As Currency
    Const myAPI As String = "apikey=xxxxxxx"
    Dim sURL As String: sURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_DAILY&from_symbol=" & sFrom & "&to_symbol=" & sTo & "&outputsize=full&"
    Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest
    Dim strJSON As String, JSON As Object
    Dim closestDate As Date
    
Set httpRequest = New WinHttpRequest
With httpRequest
    .Open "Get", sURL & myAPI
    .send
    .WaitForResponse
    strJSON = .responseText
End With
Set httpRequest = Nothing
    
Set JSON = ParseJson(strJSON)
    
With JSON("Time Series FX (Daily)")
    If IsMissing(dt) Then dt = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 31)
        
    Do Until .Exists(Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
        dt = dt - 1
    Loop
 End With

historicalForex = JSON("Time Series FX (Daily)")(Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd"))("4. close")
        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You may study my project [VBA.CurrencyExchange](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.CurrencyExchange), which will retrieve exchange rates from ten sources including XE. Code is way too much to post here, but this is the top level function for XE:

```vb
' Returns the current conversion factor from US Dollar to another currency
' based on the exchange rates published by "XE".
'
' Optionally, the conversion factor can be calculated from any other of the
' published exchange rates.
'
' If an invalid or unpublished currency code is passed, a conversion factor
' of zero is returned.
'
' Examples, typical:
'   CurrencyConvertXec("DKK")           ->  6.453107743
'   CurrencyConvertXec("DKK", "EUR")    ->  7.4699364684
'   CurrencyConvertXec("AUD")           ->  1.406057001
'   CurrencyConvertXec("AUD", "DKK")    ->  0.2178883504
'   CurrencyConvertXec("DKK", "AUD")    ->  4.5895064983
'   CurrencyConvertXec("EUR", "DKK")    ->  0.1338699471
'   CurrencyConvertXec("", "DKK")       ->  0.1549640948
'   CurrencyConvertXec("USD")           ->  1
' Examples, neutral code.
'   CurrencyConvertXec("AUD", "XXX")    ->  1
'   CurrencyConvertXec("XXX", "AUD")    ->  1
'   CurrencyConvertXec("XXX")           ->  1
' Examples, invalid code.
'   CurrencyConvertXec("XYZ")           ->  0
'   CurrencyConvertXec("DKK", "XYZ")    ->  0
'
' 2018-10-16. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CurrencyConvertXec( _
    ByVal IsoTo As String, _
    Optional ByVal IsoFrom As String = USDollarCode) _
    As Double
    
    Dim Rates()     As Variant
    
    Dim IsoBase     As String
    Dim RateTo      As Double
    Dim RateFrom    As Double
    Dim Factor      As Double
    Dim Index       As Integer
    
    If IsoFrom = "" Then
        IsoFrom = USDollarCode
    End If
    If IsoTo = "" Then
        IsoTo = USDollarCode
    End If
    
    If IsoTo = NeutralCode Or IsoFrom = NeutralCode Then
        Factor = NeutralRate
    ElseIf IsoTo = IsoFrom Then
        Factor = NeutralRate
    Else
        ' Retrieve current rates using IsoFrom as the base currency.
        IsoBase = IsoFrom
        Rates() = ExchangeRatesXec(IsoBase)
        
        ' Look up the rate of IsoFrom.
        For Index = LBound(Rates) To UBound(Rates)
            If Rates(Index, RateDetail.Code) = IsoFrom Then
                RateFrom = Rates(Index, RateDetail.Rate)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        If RateFrom > NoRate Then
            ' Look up the rate of Isoto.
            For Index = LBound(Rates) To UBound(Rates)
                If Rates(Index, RateDetail.Code) = IsoTo Then
                    RateTo = Rates(Index, RateDetail.Rate)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Factor = RateTo / RateFrom
        End If
    End If
    
    CurrencyConvertXec = Factor

End Function
```

It is, however, made for *Microsoft Access*. In *Excel*, I believe, you will need a reference to *Access* as it uses the *Collection* object of *Access VBA*.